# Spring Security - user authentication with BCrypt hashed password (bad credentials error)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

After registration of a new user, generated hashed password in database don't match password from user input typed in order to authenticate. Raw passwords are the same but hashed versions are different. I wonder how to get these two match each other for proper authentication? I'm using Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE, and 4.2.0.RELEASE for Security.

Also I have a warning:

```
WARN SpringSecurityCoreVersion:78 - **** You are advised to use Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE or later with this version. You are running: 4.3.0.RELEASE
```

Maybe this is causing a problem in some way.

config.xml:

```
<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

UserEntity.java:

```
public void setPassword(String password) {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    this.password = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
}
```

UserAuthenticationProviderService.java:

```
public boolean processUserAuthentication(UserEntity user) {

    try {
        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());
        Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);

        return true;
    } catch(AuthenticationException e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), "Catched Error!"));

        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Solved.

As Shaun said problem was encoding in Entity class. After moving encoding to place of user creation everything works well, because encoding now appears only in user creation process. Thanks!

Comment: You are using both namespace configuration and plain Java beans for the authentication manager. You should choose one or the other. Also, your question isn't really very clear. What do you mean by "hashed versions are different" - how do you know? What are you comparing and where? Are the values in the database recognisable as bcrypt hashes? Post an example and illustrate using actual (test) data what you mean.

Comment: Right after registration with password: "superman", password is saved in database as: "$2a$10$lwRt//HRsibkzHQzECHxi.E2hacnQve3JTZkxlrwlvVZ1S0w1DKO6" which is ok. But right after that, when application is trying to auto login, password in database was changed to: "$2a$10$19Z.a2KhDELFMJ55VhxQtOvaZsO0n8q2VLXUqBpxsmHfj3j3NkQjq" and stay that way. It looks like updating right password with wrong one at the same run, but right now I don't know the cause.

Comment: Update: It's not staying that way. After any try to log in it's updating (updated still don't match)

Comment: Spring Security doesn't update your database - you must be doing that elsewhere. You should debug those changes and work out where they are coming from and what the values are that are being hashed. The entity code is confusing. If that is the database entity, why are you using the password from that to authenticate? It looks like you are taking an already hashed password and passing it to the AuthenticationManager, which will hash it again during the check (and this will obviously fail).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you noted right after 2 encoding of the same string by BCryptEncoder you will get different strings. But Spring Security doesn't use matching for equals. When you register you encoder, SPring Security would use `boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword)` from PasswordEncoder(BCryptEncoder implements this interface).

If you are interesting about details, you can view implementation of BCrypt, its pretty simple:

```
static boolean equalsNoEarlyReturn(String a, String b) {
        char[] caa = a.toCharArray();
        char[] cab = b.toCharArray();

        if (caa.length != cab.length) {
            return false;
        }

        byte ret = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < caa.length; i++) {
            ret |= caa[i] ^ cab[i];
        }
        return ret == 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still can't understand why Spring Security doesn't match these passwords using matches() function while encoder is definded as BCrypt in securiy config file. Is it possible that authenticationManager.authenticate() doesn't recognise that passwords are BCrypt hashed and comparing them as raw?

Comment: @rchtp It does recognize that as BCrypt when you explicitly say so by auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()); I did not have to change anything but that when I switched to BCrypt.